# Dynamically removing a member from Expando /dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject, dynamicobject

I'm looking for a way to remove members dynamically from an dynamic object (may be can we use Expando object here?).

OK, I guess a little clarification is needed...

When you do that :

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.Bar = 42;
foo.Jar = 25;
```

The `Bar`, 'jar' property will be added dynamically at runtime.  I am displaying this to user , he may further add his own properties (form available option), this can be done by just adding member to dynamic object.

But he can also remove members (say 'Jar') form the Foo object, how do we remove the member form dynamic object? Can we use Expando object here?